# PySide/PyQt: insert data/table from database to another database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pyqt, pyside

working with PySide.
I have a sqlite database as default database:

```
db1 = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db1.setDatabaseName(path_of_db)
db1.open()
```

and a second database with connection name "second_db":

```
db2 = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE", "second_db")
db2.setDatabaseName(path_of_db)
db2.open()
query = QSql.QSqlQuery("second_db")
query.exec_("SELECT * FROM table_name")
```

Now i want to insert records from a table from `db1` into a table from `db2`. I have a model for db1. I know that I can insert record per record through the models. I also thought about writing the records from `db1` in a file/variable and then insert these into `db2`.
Is there a simpler/quicker solution maybe a sql-query? How can I solve the problem?

Thank you for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try row by row insertion, and see how fast it is. Might be all you need. A few tips on bulk insertions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite); basically,if you use BEGIN and END TRANSACTION, and an in-memory journal then you greatly speed up inserts. Oh and create indexes after you're done, not before.